# Dynamic Quorum behaviour with a witness

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering

I was going through [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4440/understand-how-dynamic-witness-works-for-a-sql-server-wfsc/) article and trying to understand the behaviour described in the article.

> Summary - It is not a common scenario to see cluster nodes go offline
> until the last node and the FSW is also unavailable. But in the
> scenario outlined in this tip, the cluster will shutdown because it
> can no longer achieve a quorum majority. In a cluster with a witness,
> quorum votes are not adjusted when it is below 3 unlike the quorum
> type Node Majority. At least two quorum votes are required to continue
> running a cluster with a witness. **This behavior is by design, so the
> cluster can recover from a partitioned scenario**.  This scenario makes
> sense to put the FSW in a third data center if possible. As with any
> implementation, understanding the fundamentals of a Windows cluster
> allows an administrator to design a better solution

Why is this behavior by design and what is the partitioned scenario the article is talking about?  Also, mainly I am confused about how this scenario(with a file share) is different from when the cluster is in node majority quorum only and what is the specific thing that is preventing it from adjusting the vote down to a single vote so that it gets to the last man standing scenario?

Answer (score 4):

First, I do want to point out that there are portions of the linked article that are incorrect, however that does not change the part you've quoted which is correct.

> Why is this behavior by design and what is the partitioned scenario the article is talking about?

If you have a 2 node cluster with a witness, if the cluster becomes partitioned there is only a single way that occurs - neither node can talk/see each other. There is no other option. The cluster has 2 partitions, each node being their own partition at this point since they only know of themselves. In order to achieve quorum a majority of the votes are required, which in this case would be 2 out of 3 votes. Whomever achieves control over the witness is the partition that is promoted to being in charge of the cluster and the one that loses will shutdown (not physically, talking about clustering) with various different logged items (either witness paxos tag is higher or reservation failed, depending on witness type).

> Also, mainly I am confused about how this scenario(with a file share) is different from when the cluster is in node majority [...]

Since there is a witness, the witness is used for arbitration. In a node-majority scenario there is no witness, only node votes. There is nothing to arbitrate. You either have a majority of the votes, or you don't.

> [...] and what is the specific thing that is preventing it from adjusting the vote down to a single vote so that it gets to the last man standing scenario?

In a node majority it *can* do that under *very* specific circumstances. Things like rebooting a node that has communications with the other nodes in the cluster will allow you to get down to a single node. The key is the cluster cannot lose half or more of their nodes in a node-majority cluster as that would indeed cause the cluster to go offline. Again, this only works when the cluster loses less than half the nodes at a time and the cluster has ample time to reconfigure itself after losing the nodes before losing more - or if nice shutdowns are completed.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  So in the situation that you described with nodes being not able to talk to each other -  after one node takes control of the witness, why doesn't the dynamic quorum mechanism take out the vote for the witness and the other node and just have one vote for the active node so that it could sustain a further witness failure and still be active, similar to a three node, node majority setup where the nodes fail sequentially and the cluster have time to adjust the quorum?

Comment: There always needs to be an odd number of votes when the witness exists, thus with two nodes, the lowest amount is 3, not 1. In a node majority there is no witness, so it can adjust down to 1.